# nested query error with where clause

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in this query.
 I want to retrieve a data from a table by comparing with other column of table.

error is: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [news_id], [news_title] FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + DropDownList1.Text + "' AND (SELECT DISTINCT[authority] FROM [user_data] WHERE [authority]<>'trusted')";
```

Comment: I think you need to take a closer look at how to properly use `AND` with nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not doing any comparison with this condition:

```
AND (SELECT DISTINCT[authority] FROM [user_data] WHERE [authority]<>'trusted')
```

This is just returning a distinct list of items, and furthermore, is not being compared with something. Remember that statements on the WHERE clause are comparisons that results in a boolean value.